# rounded navigation bar image iphone sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I am trying to set the navigation bar's `titleView` to a rounded image. Similar to profile images you generally see in messaging applications.

I believe I should be able to create a rounded scaled down image by doing the following:

```
UIImageView* profileImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:logoImage];
[profileImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];

//profileImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
// XXX contentMode commented out because enabling it causes the rounded corners to have no effect?
profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
profileImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.navigationItem.titleView = profileImageView;
```

This appears to create the image I desire for a split second when I load the emulator, but the image appears in the top left corner of the screen and then immediately snaps to the center of the navigation bar. Once at the center of the navigation bar it rescales to take up the entire space of the navigation bar instead of remaining as a small circle. What I missing? It seems like I must need to disable what ever mechanism is causing my image to scale up to fill the entire navigation bar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add it to a contain view

```
 UIView * containView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
UIImageView* profileImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpeg"]];
[profileImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
profileImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[containView addSubview:profileImageView];
self.navigationItem.titleView = containView;
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Hey this works great, but how can i add a white border to the rounded image?

Comment: _profileImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0F;_
 
    _profileImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;_